# Terminating an AWS Code Deployment with Java jar return value

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, junit, aws-code-deploy

I have an aws instance running with webservices that I want to test with a java application running JUnit. If I have a script that runs the jar during the validate services step of the code deploy process how does the code deployment handle the return value of the jar if a test fails?

Is it required that I catch exceptions thrown by the jar for the failing tests and call `system.exit(-1)` to have the script terminate the code deployment or does the exception thrown automatically give the return value of non-zero?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running JUnit using JunitCore, it should return a non-zero exit code if any of the tests fail.

> main
>
> public static void main(String... args)
>
> Run the tests contained in the classes named in the args. If all tests run successfully, exit with a status of 0. Otherwise exit with a status of 1. Write feedback while tests are running and write stack traces for all failed tests after the tests all complete.
>
> Parameters:
>
> ```
>    args - names of classes in which to find tests to run
> ```

From: http://junit.org/apidocs/org/junit/runner/JUnitCore.html#main%28java.lang.String...%29